How do I turn off subtitles in Hogwarts Legacy?
By default, subtitles are turned on in Hogwarts Legacy.
I've scanned through the settings, but I'm not able to find a place to turn off subtitles. It's quite irritating.
Every time I walk past someone and they speak, then what they're saying is popping up at the bottom of my screen. Sometimes multiple subtitles even overlap each other. It's just a mess. I'd like to turn off subtitles.
Is there a way to turn off subtitles in Hogwarts Legacy?

i like subtitles

In Settings, Audio options, you can toggle subtitles:


Ah. Thank you. I found it.
